# Определение местоположения в WebView Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, webview, геолокация

В моем сайте есть определение местоположения. Оно отлично работает но только в браузере.
Я пытался сделать так чтоб и в WebView работало, однако ничего не вышло.

Код

```
WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView = new WebView(this);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath(this.getFilesDir().getPath());

    final Activity activity = this;

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ukl_component-header')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
            setContentView(webView);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }

            // Otherwise allow the OS to handle things like tel, mailto, etc.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new android.webkit.WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()");

            final boolean remember = false;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UklonActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Locations");
            builder.setMessage("Would like to use your Current Location ")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("https://m.uklon.com.ua/order");

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Буду благодарен если скинете пример кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть никто и не помог я смог решить проблему и пишу этот ответ для тех кто столкнется с тем же.
Проблема заключалась в том что приложением с API 23+ недостаточно задать разрешение в файле манифеста его надо запрашивать у пользователя.

В файле манифеста все равно надо прописать разрешение на использование местоположения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

И теперь чтобы запросить у пользователя разрешение надо прописать следующее

```
private final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UklonActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Если пользователь даст разрешение повторный вызов диалогового окна с запросом на разрешение не произойдет. Однако если пользователь отключит службу сам либо не даст разрешение оно будет повторно появляться.